# Is there a theoretical limit on the smallest angle that can be used in a quantum rotation gate?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer, quantum-error-correction

Assuming ideal conditions and no error, what is the smallest $\theta>0$ that can be used in $R_x(\theta)$ or $R_y(\theta)$.

Comment: epsilon, of course!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your title asks "Is there a theoretical limit": No, there is no theoretical limit.

(And even if our gates in practice have some noise, we can use quantum error correction to perform gates to any desired accuracy.)